# Regex validator on display name for hyphen(-) value

Tags: validation, field, regex

I need to create a regex field validator on display name such that it should not have hyphen(-) unless if there is any date in the name.

| Display Name | Validation Error/ Allowed |
| --- | --- |
| This is a Display Name | Allowed |
| This is a-Display Name | Validation error. There is a "-" in between **a** and **Display** |
| 01-01-2023 This is Display Name | Allowed |
| 01-01-2023 This is Display-Name | Validation Error. There is a "-" in between **Display** and **Name** |

This regex validates DATE: `"^((19 | 20)[0-9][0-9])[- /.](0[1 - 9] | 1[012])[- /.](0[1 - 9] |[12][0 - 9] | 3[01])"`

This regex validates "-"(HYPHEN): `"[-]"`

I don't know how to merge both and make my use cases work. Any experts here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What value is there having a date in the name? A date field would be better for searching and reduces the likelihood you'll ever need to rename the item.

Comment: You have regex that validates if it is a date. Why dont you add another check which just checks if it contains hyphen for e.g. if(string.Contains("-")){ if(string.matchesRegex){return true; } else {return false;}} return true; This is not code and simply written to explain the logic. You can improve it.

Comment: Can you explain your reasoning behind this approach?

Comment: ChatGPT can help you with regex generation, however it is not clear why you would need validation in the first place, unless you're using the display name as a driver for real functionality such as URL generation.

Comment: @MichaelWest: Thanks for responding. We have some articles where content authors need dates to be in their Display Name field. And as a best practice, we don't want hyphen in Names except dates as we are using Display Names for URL generation.. I am going to try out Marek's regex below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just join:

- `date + only not hyphens` pattern:

  `^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[-/.](0[1-9]|1[012])[-/.]((19|20)[0-9][0-9])[^\-]+$`

with

- `only not hyphens` pattern:

  `(^[^\-]+$)`

using *or* `|`

Final regex is:

```
(^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[-/.](0[1-9]|1[012])[-/.]((19|20)[0-9][0-9])[^\-]+$)|(^[^\-]+$)
```

Btw I changed the order of date and year in your pattern so it matches now `01-01-2023` instead of `2023-01-01` like in your regex.

Comment: Thank you. I will try it out.

Comment: I can confirm the Regex is working Great !! Thanks again @Marek